# Pseudo-Riemannian Metric on Manifold

Tags: riemannian-geometry

In Riemannian geometry, we have

> **Proposition** *Any Manifold has a Riemannian metric*.

However, we cannot place the proof on pseudo-Riemannian situation because we do not hold the signature on manifold. So my question is

- Is there always a pseudo-Riemannian metric on manifold, which satisfies signature $(s,v)$?
- If not, what condition on manifold keeps it having the pseudo-Riemannian metric?

Any advice is helpful. Thx.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition for a smooth $n$-manifold $X$ to admit a metric of signature $(r, s)$ is that the tangent bundle admits a direct sum decomposition into a bundle of rank $r$ and a bundle of rank $s$, or equivalently that the tangent bundle admits a [reduction of the structure group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_the_structure_group) to $GL_r \times GL_s$.

When either $r$ or $s$ is equal to $1$ this is equivalent to the existence of a nonvanishing vector field, which is automatic when $X$ is noncompact and governed by whether $\chi(X) = 0$ otherwise, by the [Poincaré–Hopf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Hopf_theorem).

In general I think it's a difficult question to determine when this reduction is possible. There are necessary conditions coming from [characteristic classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_class) which show that, for example, an even-dimensional sphere $S^{2n}$ does not admit a metric of any indefinite signature. A sufficient condition is that the manifold smoothly [fibers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle) over an $r$-manifold (or an $s$-manifold).

Comment: Can you please introduce a reference that explains these results?

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't answer the general question, but Proposition 5.37 from O'Neill's *Semi-Riemannian Geometry* might be of interest:

**Proposition.** For a smooth manifold $M$ the following are equivalent:

(1) There exists a Lorentz metric on $M$.

(2) There exists a time-orientable Lorentz metric on $M$.

(3) There is a nonvanishing vector field on $M$.

(4) Either $M$ is noncompact, or $M$ is compact and Euler number $\chi(M)=0$.

Comment: Can you please introduce a reference that explains these results?

Comment: @QGravity: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3197969/39599) may be of interest.