# Why the proof of existence of Riemannian metric does not apply to pseudo Riemannian metric?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, semi-riemannian-geometry

I just looked on the proof in Wikipedia [Existence of Riemannian metric on smooth manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Every_smooth_manifold_has_a_Riemannian_metric), but I don’t see why this proof failed for pseudo-Riemannian metric, could anyone point out why this is not applicable for pseudo-Riemannian metric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails even at the pointwise level: in the Riemannian case,
$$\tag{1} \sum_\beta \tau_\beta g_\beta$$
is always positive definite since $g_\beta >0$, $\tau _\beta \ge 0$ and $\tau_{\beta_0} >0$ for some $\beta_0$. But if each $g_\beta$ is only non-degenerate, then (1) might give you a degenerate symmetric two tensor.

Related question about the existence of Puesdo Riemannian metric: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438801/pseudo-riemannian-metric-on-manifold?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thank you for clear explanation! The related question linked is also great!

Answer (score 4):

Just an example: a sum of two metrics of signature $(1,1)$ can be the zero metric:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 \end{matrix}\right)+ \left(\begin{matrix}-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for a concrete example!